# Text editor to run parts of a script

Tags: python

Occasionally my script doesn't work, so I cut parts of it out and paste it in a notepad document. Then I retrieve it back..this is tedious work.

Is there a way in blender text editor to run parts of a script?

Comment: Multiple text windows? You can setup a new "Screen" to hold them. Or create a add-on that contains your scripts with shortcut keys/menu to activate them.